# routerLinkActive in Angular 4 doesn't add class when only parameter changes

Tags: angular, routerlink, routerlinkactive

I have a problem with routerLinkActive in angular 4. I have this setup.

```
export const FruitRoutes = [
    {
        path: 'fruits/:id', component: FruiteNav,
        children: [
            {path: '', component: FruitGeneral},
            {path: 'settings', component: FruitSettings}
        ]
    }
];
```

It's a tab page for a single fruit. Ex: fruits/4 (general tab) and fruits/4/settings (settings tab)

The tab navigator (FruitNav) is set up like following and it works in most of the cases:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a [routerLink]="['/fruits', fruitId]" class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">General</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a [routerLink]="['/fruits', fruitId,'settings']" class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active">Settings</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Now the si problem: The route is currently at fruits/4. If I am within any of the child tabs or even in main nav class, and call for another fruitId, the routerLinkActive won't work. Ex:

```
<a style="color:#fff" [routerLink]="['/fruits', 5,'settings']" class="nav-link">Test</a>
```

will navigate to fruit/5 but none of the tabs will be active/selected

A typical usecase could be a list of similar fruits that the user could navigate to.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. My route configuration was not correctly setup. 
The 'parent' route should redirect to my 'default tab' route, like this:

```
export const FruitRoutes = [
    {
        path: 'fruits/:id', component: FruiteNav,
        children: [
            {path:'',redirectTo: 'general',pathMatch: 'full'}, 
            {path: 'general', component: FruitGeneral},
            {path: 'settings', component: FruitSettings}
        ]
    }
];
```

Then I changed the routerLink for the general tab link to:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a [routerLink]="['/fruits', fruitId,'general']" class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active">General</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a [routerLink]="['/fruits', fruitId,'settings']" class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active">Settings</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Tada! it works!